# Get text from voice command with Alexa echo dot

Tags: echo, node-red, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am trying to create a new skill with Alexa Skill Kit and node-red. I created a web service and linked alexa to it. Now when I call the service via voice command with Alexa Echo dot I don't get the raw text (transcription of my voice). I only got the intents and slots...

Did anyone try that ? Did I miss something while configuring Alexa Skill ?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon do not make the whole transcript available only the parts that match an intent and the extracted slots.

You used to be able to get this data but it was deprecated  for US users and never made available to users in other regions.